# awk set command line options in script

Tags: awk

I'm curious about how to set command-line options in awk script, like -F for field separator. I try to write the shebang line like

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -F ":" -f
```

and get the following error:

```
awk: 1: unexpected character '.'
```

For this example, I can do with

```
BEGIN {FS=":"}
```

but I still want to know a way to set all those options. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

let's use another example that should be easy to test.
inputfile:

```
1
2
3
4
```

test.awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -d -f
{num += $1}
END { print num}
```

run

```
/usr/bin/awk -d -f test.awk inputfile
```

will get `10` and generate a file called awkvars.out with some awk global variables in it.
but

```
./test.awk inputfile
```

will get

```
awk: cmd. line:1: ./test.awk
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: ./test.awk
awk: cmd. line:1:   ^ unterminated regexp
```

if I remove '-d' from shebang line,

```
./test.awk inputfile
```

will normally output 10.

My question is that whether there is a way to write "-d" in test.awk file to generate awkvars.out file?

Comment: Related: [Multiple arguments in shebang](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399690/multiple-arguments-in-shebang) . You might be able to use `#!/usr/bin/env -S awk ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering for the OP question, beyond the setting of FS.

Short Answer: you can not use multiple options with '#!', and since you need to tell awk to read the program from stdin (-f-), you are out of luck.

**Long Answer:**

When using `shebang` (#!), there is a limit of single argument (which is passed to the named programs as the 1st argument. So in general:

```
#! /path/to/prog arg1
input-1
input-2
```

Will execute `/path/to/prog arg1`, with the content of the file (including the leading shebang) available as stdin. **This is oversimplification, actual rules are more complex.**, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87560/does-the-shebang-determine-the-shell-which-runs-the-script

Given this limitation of one argument, when executing awk, the only valid and required parameter is '-f', which indicates that the awk programs is provided on STDIN. You can prepend few other options that do NOT take any argument, for example 'traditional' (e.g., '-Pf-' will force POSIX behavior).

As much as I can tell, all the 'interesting' options (setting FS, RS, ORS, ...) need to be separated from the '-f-' with a space, making it impossible to embed them into the command line, other then using the 'BEGIN { ... }' or similar in the script.

Bottom line, trying `#! /usr/bin/awk -f- -F,` will attempt to look for program is the same as `awk -f' -F'`, and will look for a file named '- -F`. Usually not very useful, and will not set the FS.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say following is our Input_file, which we are going to use for all mentioned solutions here.

```
cat Input_file
a,b,c,d
ab,c
```

---

---

***1st way of setting Field separator:*** 1st simple way will be setting `FS` value in `BEGIN` section of `awk` program file. Following is our `.awk` file.

```
cat file1.awk
BEGIN{
  FS=","
}
{
  print $1"..."$2
}
```

Now when we run the code following output will come:

```
/usr/local/bin/awk -f file1.awk Input_file
a...b
ab...c
```

---

---

***2nd way of setting field separator:*** 2nd way will be pass `FS` value before reading Input_file like as follows.

```
/usr/local/bin/awk -f file.awk FS="," Input_file
```

***Example:*** Now following is the `file.awk` file which has `awk` code.

```
cat file.awk
{
 print $1".."$2
}
```

Now when we run `awk` file with `awk -f ..` command as follows will be result.

```
/usr/local/bin/awk -f file.awk FS=","  Input_file
a..b
ab..c
```

Which means it is picking up the field separator as `,` in this above program.

---

---

***3rd way of setting field separator:*** We can set field separator in `awk -f` programs like how we do for usual `awk` programs using `-F','` option as follows.

```
/usr/local/bin/awk -F',' -f  file.awk Input_file
a..b
ab..c
```

---

---

***4th way of setting field separator:*** We could mention field separator as a variable by using `-v` option on command line while running `file.awk` script as follows.

```
/usr/local/bin/awk -v FS=',' -f  file.awk Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now that I can either assign to FS in the script file or pass as an command-line argument. I can also use -F command-line option. My question is, can I use -F option in my script rather than in the command line? If I can, how should I do it?

Comment: @Zhu, yes you can do in `BEGIN` section, I have provided 4 options to set it, kindly check them and lemme know if you find any queries on same?

Comment: these ways are fine, but except for the 3rd way which uses -F option, other ways all use variable FS. My question, in fact, is whether I can use command-line options in script, like -M for bignum, -W for gawk-opt and so on. I think that -F is just one of these options that happen to be able to be substituted by FS variable?

Comment: @Zhu, I have not used these options but if `-F` is allowed then these should also be try mine 4th option use `-v` for these options and try it once? I can't test it since I need to have a use case for it. lemme know how it goes?

Comment: I've edited the question and added an example. I think the way you mention needs an awk variable corresponding to the option?

Comment: @Zhu, I am not sure why you are using `-d`  here when I run `/usr/local/bin/awk -f file.awk Input_file` it works fine for me.

Comment: no specific reason, just to test awk options. using -d [filename] will generate a file containing some awk global files in it. If the filename is not specified, it will be 'awkvars.out'. Surely nothing will go wrong without it, I just want to find a way to specify options in the script file, and it is an example.

Comment: @Zhu, honestly I haven't explored that option yet, but your script should run by simply doing `/usr/local/bin/awk -f file.awk Input_file` where `file.awk` is having awk code.

Answer (score 0):

Never use a shebang to call awk as it robs you of the ability to separate shell arguments into awk arguments and awk variables and do anything else that's better done in shell (e.g. arg parsing with getopts) before calling awk. Just call awk from inside your shell script.

Also, don't name your shell script `test.awk` as it's a shell script. The fact it's implemented in awk is irrelevant. There's no reason to create a file that you sometimes call as `awk file` to have awk interpret and other times as just `file` to have the shell interpret.